How to insert a new row to excel file when a subfolder is created on sharepoint using power automate?
I'm trying to create a flow where when a sub-folder is created in Sharepoint, a new row is added to an excel document which has the date created, name and link to the sub-folder.
Currently I have the trigger "When a file is created (properties only)" followed by the action "Add row to table". The problem is this creates rows in excel for all the files inside the sub-folder as well which I don't want.

Add a Condition. In the Condition Parameters, check that the IsFolder property of the 'When a file is created' action is equal to true. Put your 'Add a row into a table' action in the 'True' branch of the condition.

Updated answer
Add another row in the Condition Parameters to check that the Path property is equal to the folder that you want to monitor. In my example, the Condition will be True if a folder is created in the Shared Documents/ folder. But it will be false if a folder is created in the Shared Documents/New Folder folder.


Thank you this worked great. Do you know if there's a way to not include the sub folders within the sub folder either?

@Trying I've updated the answer with a second condition
